# Kotline Updating a textview in different layout xml from the main activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I have a Activity(MainPageActivity.kt) with the corresponding xml layer(activity_main_page.xml).
I also have another xml layout called `nav_header.xml`.
in `nav_header.xml` i have a `TextView(id=drawer_user_name)`
i want to update text of TextView(drawer_user_name) from `MainPageActivity.kt`

**MainPageActivity.kt**

```
class MainPageActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    lateinit var toolbar:androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var navView:NavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page)

        toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,0,0)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        // I Try solution 1  
        val mbind = NavHeaderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        mbind.drawerUserName.text = "ssssssssss"

       // I Try solution 2  
       

        .....

    }
```

**nav_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#4cAF50"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingTop="35dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this our navigation drawer"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i use view binding but do not worked correctly(no any error)
The problem-solving method does not matter whether it is the view binding method or any other method
please help me
thank you

**Edit**

**activity_main_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_list" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:id="@+id/home_page_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Chat"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is my content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you included this nav_header.xml layout in your activity_main_page.xml?

Comment: @Shrey Garg No, I did not do this, in fact, I do not need it at all.
I edit the question and put the rest of the code to make it clearer.
In fact, nav_header.xml is a my Navigation Drawer of app

Comment: Shrey Garg   I edited question

Comment: So finding a view in a layout that is not invoked by SetContentView is quite tricky, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271955/11094201) answer is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: this[https://stackoverflow.com/a/2271955/11094201] link do not worked!!!!!!